# A migration flag, active since 2 days, is it a bug?

Tags: bug, flagging, migration

Two days ago, I flagged my post:
 "[Double coset relation for unique intermediate subgroup (with homogeneity)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724877/double-coset-relation-for-unique-intermediate-subgroup-with-homogeneity)"
for a migration on MO, but the flag is still active. Is it a bug? Else what is the normal time?

Comment: We usually migrate questions to MO only after a moderator with expertise in the relevant are has checked it and decided that it probably a good fit for MO. This can lead to longer handling times for such flags.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: Thank you! How long in general?

Comment: Hard to say, there is also th effect that on weekends many moderators are less active. Sadly, I don't feel competent to handle that flag.

Comment: The post is now migrated. Thanks to the moderator.